# 1 pixel Gif as a new measure tool? o_O BLANK_IMAGE_URL what is it for?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I'm reading ExtJs documantaion.. there is a BLANK_IMAGE_URL property... documantation says that it's a link to 1 pixel transparent Gif, that allow to corect measurements...

**How can i mesure something by 1 pixel Gif? And why is it important?**

PS: or maybe it's a big joke of ExtJs developers.. you know.. "Ha ha! one more idiot set BLANK_IMAGE_URL, what a moron!" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1px image is simplest form of creating/filling areas of web page. This is existing from long time. Here is how it works.

You want to have a strip (img) to fill a certain area (div), so that it won't collpase.  Also, other items feel its presence and adjust automatically. In those cases, instead of using empty div with fixed height and width, it is best to put an image (1px) in that div, and set the image height and width as you wish.

Since, it is a 1px single color, I doesn't matter how you stretch it, it don't loose quality, and solves the purpose.

rendering of Div or any element varies from browser to browser, and hard to achieve precision across browsers. But, if it is an Image tag, we can reasonably expect same look in any browser.

Comment: tnx a lot.. but why it's so 'bad' to set `div` width and height?

Comment: to make it fit, though we have no data in it.

Answer (score 5):

The installation guidelines for ExtJS 2 and 3 advise you to host the image yourself and in ExtJS 4 the image has even been replaced with a data uri scheme (`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==`) so it most likely isn't a tracking image but is actually used to measure with.

The (not yet complete) [ExtJS 4 docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-pr4/docs/api/Ext.html) give a better explanation:

> URL to a 1x1 transparent gif image
>   used by Ext to create inline icons
>   with CSS background images. In older
>   versions of IE, this defaults to
>   "http://extjs.com/s.gif" and you
>   should change this to a URL on your
>   server. For other browsers it uses an
>   inline data URL

this is used in the setIconCls function for example. Inthere an `<img>` tag is created with Ext.DomHelper that has this BLANK_IMAGE_URL as src and the actual icon as background. This way it's easier to scale, measure and put dimensions on it rather than using a `<div>` or `<span>` and floating or positioning it all around the space to get the right dimensions.

```
// Ext.Panel.setIconClass
setIconClass : function(cls){
    // Snip ...
    Ext.DomHelper.insertBefore(hdspan.dom, {
        tag:'img', 
        alt: '', 
        src: Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL, 
        cls:'x-panel-inline-icon '+cls
    });
    // Snip ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a tracking pixel. You're able to assemble site usage statistics by parsing access logs for requests to the pixel and it's referer.

Comment: It's unlikely to be for this reason, if (quote) `"that allow to corect measurements"`.

Comment: hmm... mb ExtJs developers track framework usage? :) (they can listen us right now, we have to be quaet)

Comment: They most likely are getting statistics from the hits on this file - a pleasant side effect :)

Comment: They could use it as tracking pixel but most likely aren't, and if they were they probably wouldn't tell you. the main reason it's there is actually to create icons with css classes with. Your tracking theory is also debunked by the fact that in ExtJS 4 the gif is replaced with a simpele data:uri so tracking is no longer possible.

Comment: It could be that Ext is secretly tracking all HTTP requests for 10's of thousands of users... or it could just be for creating image elements that get their image src from CSS.  Hmmmm.  Occam's Razor anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `blank.gif`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blank.gif

The reason it's needed is probably something to do with compatability for an old version of Internet Explorer.

See: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?16434-best-place-to-put-Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL

> BLANK_IMAGE_URL assigns the URL for a
>   1x1 transparent gif image used by Ext
>   to create inline icons with CSS
>   background images used by some
>   widgets. It defaults to
>   "http://extjs.com/s.gif" so you should
>   change this to a URL on your server.

Comment: I'm *guessing* this is required because without it, some browser (IE?) will show a "missing image" icon if you don't provide a valid image.

Comment: Here's an example of someone having a problem in IE7 because they're missing the file in question: http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?12064-SOLVED-1.0-BLANK_IMAGE_URL-Problem-IE7

Comment: mb i have to throw away this documentation... why they saying that it helps to correct some mesurements? =\

Comment: Where's the documentation that has that wording? In any case, I think I've made it clear why it is needed (see the link in my last comment).

Comment: Has nothing to do with IE.  See @ChrisR's explanation.

Comment: @bmoeskau: It does have something to do with IE. I said "The reason it's needed is probably something to do with compatability for an **old version of Internet Explorer**.". See @ChrisR's explanation yourself: "**In older versions of IE**, this defaults to "http://extjs.com/s.gif" and you should change this to a URL on your server. **For other browsers** it uses an inline data URL"